# How to enable warning for Ctrl+Enter before sending message in Outlook.com?

Tags: outlook.com

I have Ubuntu and I am using Outlook.com in a web browser, not the Desktop application. I tried Settings → Options → Mail, but there is no option to enable the warning.

Comment: I found myself in the same boat, and after several times that I accidentally sent incomplete email, I just had to disable all keyboard shortcuts.